# Python - TypeError: object of type 'Cell' has no len()

Tags: python, excel, selenium

I am working on Selenium with Python.

I am writing a code which will fetch the data from an excel file and punch the same data on the WebPortal. But I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'Cell' has no len()
```

Below is the code:

```
for X in range(1,rowCount):
    for Y in range(0,colCount):
        cellData = worksheet.cell(X,Y)

        driver.find_element_by_id("XYZ").send_keys(cellData)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a `cell` object where a string is expected.

Try this instead:

`cellData = worksheet.cell(X,Y).value`